# How to programmatically open settings popup for a shockwave-flash object

Tags: javascript, flash, shockwave, axshockwaveflash

I have an application that has an audio/video chat. I'm using a flash object on IE and Safari. Everything works fine. I was just wondering if there a way to open the "Adobe flash player settings" popup via JavaScript?

[image: settings popup]

In case you think it's relevant, this is the code for my flash object:

```
<object id="flashObject" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="video.swf">
                <param name="quality" value="high">
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#262626">
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
                <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
                <param name="scale" value="exactFit">
 </object>
```

Comment: This should be handled by the Flash app. Can you access/change the Flash file?

Comment: No, I don't... I was just wondering if there was a way of doing it via code but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Flash will automatically popup the settings the first time the swf will try to access the microphone or camera. Once the user makes a selection there the popup will not come up again.